# Page not found if mod_cache_disk is active

Tags: 404-error, cache, apache

I set in Apache the mod_cache_disk module, but I'm getting 404 page not found error on every page and posts. I'm using WordPress Multisite on Debian 10 server with PHP FPM 7.4.

I set this below in apache2.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
    CacheQuickHandler off

    CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
    CacheDefaultExpire 7200

    CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
    CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.5
    CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie Cookie
    CacheHeader on
    CacheLock on
    CacheDisable /wp-admin
    CacheDisable /wp-login.php
    CacheDisable /wp-cron.php

    SetOutputFilter CACHE
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/javascript application/rss+xml text/xml image/svg+xml

    <IfModule mod_cache_disk.c>
        CacheRoot /mnt/cache
        CacheEnable disk /
        CacheDirLevels 2
        CacheDirLength 1
        CacheMaxFileSize 100000000
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Everything is working fine if I delete these lines from the configuration file.

How can I fix this issue? I would like to use mod_cache_disk with WordPress, it makes it at least 35x faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by replacing

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

in .htaccess file.